# UITableViewCell is loading content only on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a UITableView

Here is the code sample

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t2wnpo110o2r9n/TableBug.zip?dl=0

The problem is , the UITableViewCell only shows 1 cell and shows other cells only after Scroll

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code? and not all of the project or any files to be downloaded..

Comment: @YuviGr yes i did add relevant code in earlier question and no one could figure out so i have made this a sample project, it just contains the code that needs to be checked. What else can i do.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301107/uitableview-load-content-only-on-scroll-in-xcode-6

Comment: just downloaded it...let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after running your code you have one problem.

Because you have an image as a subView of your cell and the image is larger then the cell, some time it will be drawn outside of the cell and hide other cells

So go the StoryBoard and select the table view cell and in the attribute inspector check the "clip subviews" button.

This should solve your problem (it did for me when i run your code)

Comment: the one that covers all of the cell (listBackground.png)

Comment: that fixed the loading issue but i am not been able to understand why the images are being resized out of the bounds of cell?

Comment: it seems to me that width is being altered too

Comment: because the image bound is bigger then the cell's, so you need to tell the cell to explicit clip all the views that may starch beyond it's own bounds

Comment: @YuviGr, it seems like making any size alteration to the custom cell in IB stops the problem from occurring. I resized the cell height by -2px and the problem stopped. Additionally, the first thing I tried was resizing his imageViews and UILabels and it didn't help. AND I have his code working and I don't have Clip Subviews checked, only the default Autoresize Subviews.

Comment: so only by making the cell's height smaller you managed to stop the imageView from going out of the cell's bounds?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. I did resize it and it handled the problem. Just to check again, I deleted the project and re-downloaded. I tried resizing the cell in the newly downloaded project and it didn't work that time, but Clipping Subviews did work. But in the first project, I didn't have it checked and it still worked. The imageViews were the same size both times.

Comment: I can tell you that the resizing doesn't like it will solve it. there is no difference between a cell with (height = x) and a cell with height = (x-2). I don't know why it worked and still working in the first project..

Comment: I am fully aware. I'm just saying that it is peculiar.

Comment: I agree with you :) For now this is the best solution i can offer

Comment: Well i ended up programmtically defining the height and width of all subviews. That has fixed all issues. It seems in iphone 6 and one must use autolayout or prepare for such things....